# How do I save the name of a object in another variable?

Tags: java, string

Say I have objects:

```
Animal lion = new Animal();
Animal elephant = new Animal();
Animal cheetah = new Animal();
```

How would I be able to store the names of the animals (i.e. lion, elephant, cheetah)?

I have tried using

```
for (int count = 0; count < 3; count++) {
    String name = lion.getClass().getName();
```

but this would only give me "Animal.lion", when I only want the "lion" bit.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: objects don't have "names". You are confusing object with variable, and inflating the importance of variables. What matters is not so much the variable, but rather the ***reference***.

Comment: Note: it is very surprising that you can get `"Animal.lion"` out of `new Animal().getClass().getName()` call.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but I'd like to note that it is not necessary to do the same thing (`String name = ...;`) three times to make it work. Programming isn't (black or white) magic, although sometimes it might seem so. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objects don't have "names". You are confusing object with variable, and inflating the importance of variables. What matters is not so much the variable, but rather the ***reference***.

If you want to associate an object with a String, then use a Map.

e.g.,

```
Map<String, Animal> animalMap = new HashMap<String, Animal>();
Animal lion = new Animal();
animalMap.put("lion", lion);
Animal elephant = new Animal();
animalMap.put("elephant", elephant);
Animal cheetah = new Animal();
animalMap.put("cheetah", cheetah);
```

then

```
for (String key : animalMap.keySet()) {
   System.out.printf("Animal name is %s%n", key);
}
```

---

Also note that as hakiko states well (1+ to his answer), an object can be referred to by multiple variables, and in that situation, which variable represents the "name" of the object??

Comment: I think this is closest to what I am looking for, but I don't know what the %s%n does....?

Comment: @INear: Note that I'm not using `System.out.println` but rather `System.out.printf`, and that uses format specifier Strings similar to C's printf function. You can read more about the specifics of this method in the [java.util.Formatter API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: In the second bit of code, should I assume that "animal.Map.values()" is supposed to be "animalMap.values()"?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels can I ask you a question here?

Comment: @KickButtowski what's up?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  
thanks for responding. I found one your answer for highlighting txt, but my question is how I can highlight a text any where and read it after that. My plan is to write a dictionary so when you click on a text, it gets highlighted and meaning will pop up in a window. I do not have any issue for the rest except I do not know the highlighting part . I am afraid to post cuz i may get voted down

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I encountered another problem... I can't access a name-string of a key in the Map. Is there any way I could access each, one by one?

Comment: @INear See the documentation for Map's [keySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) method.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: thanks, I used the wrong `Set` method to get keys.

Comment: @KickButtowski: Why afraid to post? It sounds like a decent question, one that would be best understood if you ask it as an independent and complete question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels so it is not off topic?

Comment: @KickButtowski: Why would you think that it would be considered off-topic? I'm certainly not an expert on what is on or off topic, but your problem sounds specific, it sounds like you could create and post a minimal example program, so it looks to be answerable.

Comment: @ the problem is I don't know how to come up with a small code.

Comment: @KickButtowski: have you broken down your large problem into constituent steps? That's the first thing to do. Next to try to solve each step, and find out where you're stuck.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes I did. the only point that I don't know is how to height lighted text and get value out of it. the rest is a piece of cake

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do this. The name you give the variable that refers to that object instance is not known to the object.

Consider that you could create multiple variables which ALL had references to the same object; the idea of "the name of" the object instance is meaningless, and this case illustrates that.

You can create a field in an object that contains a name, and assign that name when you create the object, and then retrieve that if you want to.

```
public class Television  
{  
  private String name = null;  
  public String getName() { return name; }  
  public void setName(String givenName) { name = givenName; }  
  public Sample(String givenName) { setName(givenName); }  
  // add whatever you want to this class  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can slightly change the `class Animal`.

```
class Animal
{
    private String nameOfAnimal;
    public Animal(String nameOfAnimal)
    {
        this.nameOfAnimal=nameOfAnimal;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return nameOfAnimal;
    }
}
class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         Animal lion=new Animal("lion");
         Animal elephant=new Animal("elephant");
         Animal cheetah=new Animal("cheetah");
         System.out.println(lion.getName());
         System.out.println(elephant.getName());
         System.out.println(cheetah.getName());
    }
}
```

INPUT:NOTHING
OUTPUT:

```
lion
elephant
cheetah
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why you need the "name" of the variable for but to solve your specific problem:
as the expression "String name = lion.getClass().getName();" is giving you "Animal.lion" back, you can split that string(name) and take the second part of the resulting array.

like:

- String name = lion.getClass().getName();   --> (name = "Animal.lion")
- String name = name.split("\.")[1];         --> (name = "lion")